# Is it possible to execute an IF/THEN statement using row number as the logical expression in google sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, count, logic

I am trying to count the number of cells up to a specified row in google sheets. I want my function to basically compute "if row number is <= x, then count y". Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes, this is done all the time." However, without more information, it would be difficult to recommend formula setup. From what you've said in your post, why not just use the raw number? For instance, if you want to know how many cells there are in A1:A35, do you need to count them? There are ... 35. It's always most efficient to share a link to a sample sheet with representative data, being sure to set the share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit."

Comment: Ok, I have made a sample spreadsheet with some more info. Hopefully this helps clarify what I am trying to accomplish. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zotr2t8MVU7Nw2q6fBSvYanQNVk8HGbYWm1WGCQbTsg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheet permission is set to "View Only" instead of "Anyone with the link can edit." There will not be much anyone can do, especially with custom functions in play, until you change the sharing permission to "Anyone with the link can edit."

Comment: See [ask]. Provide your code, research efforts and your attempts at achieving the goal.

Comment: Ok I just changed the edit permissions

Comment: Please clarify what is the desired outcome. Also, do you want to use Apps Script or Sheets formulas?

Answer (score 0):

TJ, I added a sheet called "Erik Help." As I stated there, I don't understand why you need script-generated custom functions to do what simple formulas can do.

The total of green rows (which I put in I2):

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E,"<>")
```

The total of yellow cells in C:C within the green range (which I put in I3):

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(C2:C,E2:E<>"",COUNTIF(C$2:C,C2:C)<=4))
```

In my added sheet, I edited the values in C:C to reflect your actual usage and applied a CF formula that highlights yellow if there are 4 or fewer repetitions. So unless I'm missing something, the two formulas above give you what you need to know without script. If you can write CF formulas to highlight certain cells, you can write similar formulas in the sheet to count those same cells fairly easily.

If I'm missing something, please clarify further.